# How exactly does SQL recursion work?

Tags: sql, recursion, hierarchy, filemaker, recursive-query

I need to write a series of queries on different tables. All of them are of the same type, a record has a parent record which can also have parent record(s).

I will eventually need to:

1. Find the highest record in the hierarchy
2. Find the lowest point in the hierarchy
3. Find all ascendants
4. Find all descendants

I'm using Filemaker Pro, and I don't believe recursive SQL queries can be run natively. There are ways to achieve all 4 things using native (recursive) functions, that could populate attributes (fields) on entities (tables) that I could then query. However, **I'd like to understand how SQL recursion works** to see if I can find a more efficient way to perform these tasks.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I know that you can use SQL to query other databases from FileMaker, but I didn't know you could use SQL to query FileMaker databases.

Comment: @zneak as of Filemaker 12, the [ExecuteSQL](http://www.filemaker.com/12help/html/func_ref3.33.6.html) function added the ability to do so.

Answer (score 2):

SQL recursion is not that common and many SQL dialects simply do not support it. FileMaker is one of them. Its SQL is fairly basic (e.g. it doesn't have `LIMIT`) and usually *less efficient* than native FileMaker approach (e.g. if you use an independent subquery, it still seems to run anew  *for each row* in the main query). That is if you work with FileMaker and are interested in recursive SQL, it's bound to be a purely academic exercise. If you're after it, then [this Wikipedia article on hierarchical and recursive SQL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchical_and_recursive_queries_in_SQL) might be a good start.

But you don't need SQL for what you're trying to do; you can do all this with rather simple FileMaker calculations. Assuming your hierarchical table uses `ID` and `Parent ID` and two relationships, `Parent` and `Child`, create the following fields:

```
Root ID =
If( IsEmpty( Parent::ID ); ID; /* else */ Parent::Root ID )

Leaf IDs = 
If( IsEmpty( Child::ID ); ID; /* else */ List( Child::Leaf IDs ) )

Ancestor IDs =
List( Case( not IsEmpty( Parent::ID ); Parent::Ancestor IDs ); ID )

Descendant IDs =
List( ID; Case( not IsEmpty( Child::ID ); List( Child::Descendant IDs ) ) )
```

As you see each field has a recursive formula that refers to itself. You won't be able to enter it right after you add the field because by this time the field is not yet saved and FileMaker will complain that it cannot find it. To work around this first create a field, save it, and then edit it again and enter the formula.

Comment: The data model I'm using uses this child/parent concept a lot to expand on the flexibility of customization (i.e. product componentization). I'm trying to figure out what other alternatives to the functions you list are out there for two reasons: 1) because it is used a lot in the data model, I was hoping I didn't have to clutter the relationship graph and 2) I'm going to have to use the results of these queries (recursive calc fields) as "where" clauses in another query, and I'm looking to better understand the whole concept to see which is the most efficient and flexible approach.

Comment: The overall issue I'm tackling is [this one](http://tinyurl.com/ko9jctv), I'd appreciate your input if you have any ideas.

Comment: `LIMIT` is not standard. It's a MySQL extension.